# IList binding Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Trying to bind IList so that I can update the fields that I have. However, ending up with an empty list with OnPostAsync. Not sure what I'm missing.

My code looks as follows:

```
[BindProperty]
public IList<Runbook_Serverlist_Plus> RunbookServerListPlus { get; set; }
```

This list is filled with the OnGetAsync function using the below code:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
   var listRunbookServerList = await _context.Runbook_Serverlist.ToListAsync();
   RunbookServerListPlus = listRunbookServerList.Select(item => new Runbook_Serverlist_Plus(item)).ToList();
}
```

So from my model I first get the IList<Runbook_Serverlist> and then I create a new list for Runbook_Serverlist_Plus.
Idea is to have a sort of a base class of Runbook_Serverlist, then put a Runbook_Serverlist_Plus on top, in which I can set specific fields which I can later use to update some fields.

See code below:

```
  public class Runbook_Serverlist_Plus
  {
    [BindProperty]
    public Runbook_Serverlist Bc {get; set; }

    public Runbook_Serverlist_Plus(Runbook_Serverlist bsBc)
    {
      Bc = bsBc;
      CheckCompleted = false;
    }
    
    public bool CheckCompleted { get; set; }
  }
```

In my cshmtl the code is as follows:

```
<form method="post">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Servername)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Status)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Cluster)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.StatusChange)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.PreRun)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Ordering)
    </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.RunbookServerListPlus.Count; i++)
  {
    var item = Model.RunbookServerListPlus[i];
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Servername)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Status)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Cluster)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.StatusChange)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.PreRun)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Ordering)
      </td>
      <td>
        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Servername" class="form-control" />
        <input asp-for="@item.CheckCompleted"  class="form-control"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
  </tbody>
</table>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</form>
```

So I have a checkbox for the CheckCompleted item and when doing a post, I would like to see all the checkboxes which are marked.
When I do a submit/post, I would expect the RunbookServerListPlus to be filled. However, this one is empty all the time.

What am I missing?

Post function is for now nothing else then:

```
      public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
      {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          return Page();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you can add hidden inputs to bind model data,form post will pass inputs' value.And .net core bind model with name attribute.If you want to bind data with list,you need to set name as `list[index].xxx`.

And If you only want to pass Runbook_Serverlist_Plus when CheckCompleted is checked,you can use js to change the name of hidden inputs to right format before form post.Here is a demo.

Models:

```
public class Runbook_Serverlist_Plus
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Runbook_Serverlist Bc { get; set; }
        public Runbook_Serverlist_Plus(Runbook_Serverlist bsBc)
        {
            Bc = bsBc;
            CheckCompleted = false;
        }
        public Runbook_Serverlist_Plus()
        {
        }
        public bool CheckCompleted { get; set; }
    }
    public class Runbook_Serverlist
    {
        public string Servername { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Cluster { get; set; }
        public string StatusChange { get; set; }
        public string PreRun { get; set; }
        public string Ordering { get; set; }


    }
```

cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Servername)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Status)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Cluster)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.StatusChange)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.PreRun)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RunbookServerListPlus[0].Bc.Ordering)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.RunbookServerListPlus.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = Model.RunbookServerListPlus[i];
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Servername)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Status)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Cluster)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.StatusChange)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.PreRun)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bc.Ordering)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@item.CheckCompleted" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[index].CheckCompleted" />
                        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Servername" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[index].Bc.Servername" />
                        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Status" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[index].Bc.Status" />
                        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Cluster" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[index].Bc.Cluster" />
                        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.StatusChange" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[index].Bc.StatusChange" />
                        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.PreRun" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[index].Bc.PreRun" />
                        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Ordering" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[index].Bc.Ordering" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $("form").submit(function () {
        var index = 0;
        $("tbody tr").each(function () {
            var lasttd = $(this).find('td:last-child');
            
            if (lasttd.find("input")[0].checked) {
                lasttd.find("input").each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace("index",index));
                })
                index++;
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

cshtml.cs(I use fake data to test):

```
[BindProperty]
        public List<Runbook_Serverlist_Plus> RunbookServerListPlus { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            RunbookServerListPlus = new List<Runbook_Serverlist_Plus> {
                new Runbook_Serverlist_Plus { Bc = new Runbook_Serverlist { Cluster = "c1", Ordering = "1", PreRun="p1", Servername="sname1", Status="status1", StatusChange="statuschange1" } },
                new Runbook_Serverlist_Plus { Bc = new Runbook_Serverlist { Cluster = "c2", Ordering = "2", PreRun="p2", Servername="sname2", Status="status2", StatusChange="statuschange2" } },
                new Runbook_Serverlist_Plus { Bc = new Runbook_Serverlist { Cluster = "c3", Ordering = "3", PreRun="p3", Servername="sname3", Status="status3", StatusChange="statuschange3" } }

            };
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

result:
[image]

**Update(Pass a whole list):**

Firstly,remove js in the first demo.

And then change td like this:

```
<td>
                    <input asp-for="@item.CheckCompleted" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[@i].CheckCompleted" />
                    <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Servername" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[@i].Bc.Servername" />
                    <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Status" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[@i].Bc.Status" />
                    <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Cluster" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[@i].Bc.Cluster" />
                    <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.StatusChange" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[@i].Bc.StatusChange" />
                    <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.PreRun" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[@i].Bc.PreRun" />
                    <input hidden asp-for="@item.Bc.Ordering" class="form-control" name="RunbookServerListPlus[@i].Bc.Ordering" />

                </td>
```

result:
[image]

Check data passed to handler:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and demo! 
However, if I copy the code to a new project, I still end up with an empty "RunbookServerListPlus". Not sure what I'm missing, compared to your code.

As I later want to add more field than only CheckCompleted, would it be possible to get back the whole initialized list (which is actually a list coming from SQL) and the checkboxes?

Comment: For your empty list,can you share your code?So that I can try to find the reason why your list is empty.` As I later want to add more field than only CheckCompleted, would it be possible to get back the whole initialized list (which is actually a list coming from SQL) and the checkboxes?`Do you mean you want to get the whole list even CheckCompleted is false?

Comment: Yes I want to have the whole list, even is CheckCompleted is false (because later I want to add more items like CheckCompleted). 
But after reading your comment again and changing my code to: ```<input asp-for="RunbookServerListPlus[i].CheckCompleted" class="form-control" />```, it seems to work! So thank your very much for that tip!

Comment: Regarding the demo, I created a new project, added a new cshtml with the name TestModel and pasted your code in that cshtml. But when I debug the OnPost I see an empty RunbookServerListPlus after checking one of the checkboxes.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a demo.` But when I debug the OnPost I see an empty RunbookServerListPlus after checking one of the checkboxes. `Can you share the data you pass in your request ?Have you added the js ,and can js work?

Comment: Thanks again! I do like your answer, it is much nicer than my initial attempt. I'm pretty new in the topic (but you probably already noticed :) ), but I added the js code as you provided. Not sure how I can check if js can work?

Comment: If you are using chrome to test,you can click F12 and refresh page and check Sources in it,set breakpoint to js and click submit button,then you can debug your js.

Comment: Or you can just try to click submit button,and check Network,see the OnPostRequest Headers.Check the gif I added to my answer.

Comment: Ah thanks. I still see 'index' in my application. So probably js is not working correctly. I also have this error in console of Chrome: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" probably referring to: ```$("form").submit```. Am I missing code to make js work?

Comment: Maybe I know why.Check if you put js into `@sectionScripts{}`..net core application need to put js in it.Check the picture in my answer.

Comment: Great! That's it. Thanks much. Very nice with the gifs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the handlers fires on each request, depending on the HTTP verb that was used to make the request. `OnGet` is executed when the page is requested using HTTP Get method. `OnPost` is executed by the POST method.

The web is stateless. That means that variables initialised on one request are not available to another request. If you want to work with the collection in the `OnPost` method, you need to instantiate it again in the `OnPost` handler.

More details on my site here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Comment: Thank you for your response and the link to your website (very useful for me :) ). My idea was that with the form post, I was posting again the whole table, including the textboxes. How to do that?